# Enforce suffix in typed string literals

Tags: typescript

Consider the following types:

```
type Extent = number | /.*px/ | /.*pt/;

interface Size {
  width: Extent;
  height: Extent;
}
```

Of course that's not legal TypeScript, but my intention is to enforce some suffixes in string literal types. I guess that's not possible at all, but does someone know an elegant solution?

EDIT:

Looks like that might be possible in TypeScript 4.1.0. I just saw: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336

So, I tried with the nightly playground:

```
type Extent<T extends number> = number | `${T}px` | `${T}pt`;

const ex1 : Extent<number> = 42;
const ex2 : Extent<number> = '42px';
const ex3 : Extent<number> = '42uu'; // <-- should fail!
```

But the line with `ex3` didn't fail...

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-dev.20200913#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHsCA7YAeAKlCDkBMDOUSArgLYBGEATgHxQC8RZlVUAPlAAYAkA3ugF8wcTuy59BYYJwDcAKDkBjAPZJ8wLHACMUAFywcKVCQrU6jACwAmeSrUbsVvQcRGTLc1ADk14V9uq6poAzM7wrmjuZgze1sTE-lAA9ElQqAC06VD4ABbKxAA2uFAAZgCGAJYFAIRyQA)

Comment: TypeScript doesn't perform type validation at runtime... so it's up to you to implement checking of the value against regex instead of relying on TypeScript.

Comment: I am just seeing this one: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40538) has been fixed by [this pull request](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40598).

That can be verified in [this playground example](https://www.staging-typescript.org/play?ts=4.1.0-pr-40598-20#code/C4TwDgpgBAyglgL2gXigAwCQG8B2BXAWwCMIAnAXzAA80BuAKDh2DIDMBDAY2gDEB7PlCz0ooqAGdEEAFywpDcvU58c44FD4BrKLP6CoqLJKSyARABYATNVNRyDZavUc4AG3E6oeg0OMyoFpam9qIA9KFeAIIAkgAyMFDsHhBUkJwsACb09KwCABSBNgCUDLl8BVamJeFRcQlJUClpmdmseDjpcCpQZXkA%20uIIsvBIRULkQA):

```
type Size = `${number}px`;

interface Foo {
    size: Size;
}

function foo(_sz: Size) {}

const ok : Foo  = {size: "42px" };
foo("42px");

const fails : Foo = {size: "42"};  // FAILS as expected
foo("42");                         // FAILS as expected
```